# How can I transmit session in Django?

Tags: python, django

## login.html

```
`<h2>Login</h2>
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
</form>
<a href="{% url 'loggedin' %}"><input type="submit" value="login" /></a>`
```

## loggedin.html

```
`<h2>login success</h2>`
```

## views.py

```
`def signin(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
            form = LoginForm(request.POST) #form = email, password
            email_input = str(request.POST['email'])
            password_input = str(request.POST['password'])
            user_Qset = Profile.objects.filter(email = email_input)

            if user_Qset is not None: 
                password_saved = str(user_Qset.values('password')[0]['password']) 
                if password_input == password_saved: 
                    response = render(request, 'registration/login.html',)

                    request.session.modified = True 

                    request.session['name'] = user_Qset.values('name')[0]['name']
                    request.session['email'] = user_Qset.values('email')[0]['email']
                    request.session['password'] = user_Qset.values('password')[0]['password']

                    return response

def loggedin(request):
    if request.session.has_key('name'):
        return HttpResponse("transmission success")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("transmission failed")`
```

I have a result 'transmission failed'. How can I transmit sessions I added?
When I push the login button, page url and templates should be changed and session be transmitted

When user log in, I want give user session keys(name, email, password)
I want to check session keys I gave is maintained well in another page

Comment: You should return proper error messages if the `if` conditions were not met.

Comment: where is wrong ? if session has the key 'name', print 'success' and unless session doesn't have the key 'name' print 'failed'